# Relationship through several tables

Tags: php, laravel

Tell me, I have Eloquent models:

```
- countries; 
- regions;
- cities;
- schools;
- users;
```

Relations:

```
Countries -> hasMany -> Regions<br>
Regions -> hasMany -> Cities<br>
Cities -> hasMany -> Schools<br>
Schools <-> hasManyToMany <-> Users (through table)
```

How do I get all users from the Country, via realtionship?

Comment: Something like `$user->School->->City->Region->Country` should do the trick, assuming the ORM has been properly configured.

Comment: @Max User have many schools. $user->school return collection.

Comment: Then you have two choices: (1) Assume the country will be the same for all schools a user is attending.  In this case you can use `$user->School[0]->City->Region->Country` or (2) Assume a user may attend schools in multiple countries.  In this case you need to return an array of countries the user is associated with.  But re-reading the question it looks like you want a list of all users with a school in a given country.  If that's the case, you should probably use a direct SQL query to find the relevant user IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

You can always loop through collections as if they are arrays

```
$user = \App\User::all();
$users = array();
foreach ($user->Schools as $schools)
{
   foreach ($schools->city as $cities)
   {
      foreach ($cities->region as $regions)
      {
         foreach ($regions->country as $country)
         {
             if ($country == 'YourCountry'); {
             $users [] = $users->name;
             }
```

You get all the users, based on that country name in the `$users` array.

Not sure, this is exactly what you're looking for, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$country = \App\Country::find(1);
$users = [];

foreach ($country->regions as $region)
{
    foreach ($region->cities as $city)
    {
        foreach ($city->schools as $school)
        {
            $users [] = $scholl->users;
        }
    }
}
```

`$users` would hold all users of the country with id 1.